# Modulo a composite number same as modulo individual factors?

Tags: modular-arithmetic, quadratic-residues

Can somebody please give me a hint why the following holds (or doesn't it?):

if $r^2 \equiv a \mod n$ and $n = p * q$,

then $r^2 \equiv a \mod p$

and $r^2 \equiv a \mod q$.

I tried it with different examples, it seems to hold but I don't have an idea why. Also, if it holds, does a rule exist for it? The name of the rule would be enough, so I can do further research on it.

Example: $r = 23$, $p = 7$, $q = 11$, then:

$23^2 \equiv -10 \mod 77$

$23^2 \equiv 1 \mod 11 \equiv -10 \mod 11$

$23^2 \equiv 4 \mod 7 \equiv -10 \mod 7$

Comment: Search for "Chinese Remainder Theorem" and you will see how best to understand the implication.  Note that if $r^2=a$, then of course $r^2 \equiv a \mod n$ for every modulus.

Comment: $r^2 \equiv  a\pmod{n}$ says that $n$  divides $r^2-a$. If $p$ divides $n$ and $n$ divides $r^2-a$, then $p$ divides $r^2-a$, that is, $r^2\equiv a\pmod{p}$.

Comment: [Continuing André's comment] Note also that there is nothing special about $r^2$. In general, $r \equiv a \mod n$ implies $r \equiv a \mod p$ for any factor $p$ of $n$.

Answer (score 3):

If $r^2 = kn + a$ for some $k\in\Bbb Z$, then
$$r^2 = \left(kq\right)p+a = \left(kp\right)q + a$$